# Underscore method _.template() doesn't compile my template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, backbone.js

I'm getting started with backbone.js and i want to build a template, containing only a html button, with my model attributes. So I defined a template in my html page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<title>Backbone test 5</title>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone_test5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="here"></div>

<script type="text/template" id ="button_template">
<button type="button" id="my_button"><%= text %></button>
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

and I'm trying to build my template in my view:

```
var Bouton_View= Backbone.View.extend({

    view_template: _.template( $('#button_template').html() ),

    events:{
    'click':'onClick'
    },

    initialize: function(){
    this.$el=('#here');
    },

    render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.view_template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
    },

    onClick: function(){
    var increment=0;
    increment=this.Model.get("number_of_click")+1;
    this.Model.set({"text":increment});
    this.Model.set({"number_of_click":increment});
    this.render();

    }

});
```

but when I run the page in the browser this error message show up:

[image: error message in underscore.js screenshot]

I'm pretty sure the `js file` is not wrong because I've try this with another html file and it worked. So what is wrong with my template? thanks in advance

Comment: when you console.log `$('#button_template').html()` what does it say?

Comment: that prints me "undefined"

Comment: Well that's your problem then, the code you provided works so it's something you haven't put here - http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/thep19q7/

Comment: hmm i've try that but it still doesn't work :/ the issue is in underscore file which seems to not recognize my html template

Comment: Your JavaScript is being run before `#button_template` is available. Move your `<script id="button_template">` before your JavaScripts, wrap your JavaScript in a `$(function() { ... })` wrapper, or do your `_.template` call inside your view's `initialize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why so?

**Spoiler**: the underscore templating engine is fine in this case.

This example's problem is that the code which describes your `Bouton_View`, which probably lies here:

```
<script src="backbone_test5.js"></script>
```

is executed before the DOM parser reaches

```
<script type="text/template" id ="button_template">
<button type="button" id="my_button"><%= text %></button>
</script>
```

element. This can be described as

1. Load `backbone_test5.js` file and execute its contents
2. Execute `_.template( $('#button_template').html() )`

   - Search DOM for element with `id="button_template"`
   - None found
   - Execute `.html()` function on a non-existent `$` element => this results in `null`
   - Execute `_.template(null)` => this gives you the error you mentioned

#### How to fix?

There are several ways to do that.

**HTML-only.** Re-order the code so that DOM elements exist when queried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Backbone test 5</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="here"></div>

        <script type="text/template" id ="button_template">
        <button type="button" id="my_button"><%= text %></button>
        </script>

        <script src="underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="backbone_test5.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**With some js-code.** You can wrap the contents of the `backbone_test5.js` file with the `$(...)` so that it only executes once the DOM content is ready:

```
$(function () {
    var Bouton_View = Backbone.View.extend({ /* ... */ });
});
```

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN Glad we helped! Consider upvoting the answer or marking it as accepted, or both.